# Realm data gets lost after some time

Tags: swift, realm

I am using Realm with Swift and I have the problem, that after some time my data gets lost.
As an example I have a user entity which is loaded in a singleton class directly from the realmstore and then displayed on the views etc...

So I assume, that it's bad practice to load the user every time I need it from the realm store, is that correct?

Should I make a business logic user class which is practically the same than the realm object and load the user once? and only if I change the business logic user I store it into the realm again?

Is it possible that this causes the realm store at any time to be damaged that the object cannot be accessed anymore?

best regards

Comment: Define what you mean by `data is lost`, any change done to the Realm is reflected in the managed objects that exist.

Comment: Are you trying to save and retrieve user data and settings, let's say name, application preferences, etc?

Comment: within the appstart i try to receive the user from the realm storage. i fetch all user entities and return the first (i only have one stored) but after some time, and i dont know what happens in the meantime, the fetch returns no user anymore, but i dont delete the user at any time. there is no delete method for a user. the only thing i do is to update the properties within the dictionary update way. With retrieving user data and settings do you mean different realm objects which are stored? yes i have different object types. all of them, except the user can be deleted

Comment: could it be a problem, that i created a singleton class RealmManager, which handles all my realm transactions. One level above i have different repositories which store and load derived Realm objects within the RealmManager. So i call the Realm() call only once in the entire application and i saw that it can fail or it actually fails sometimes. Singletons in Swift should be thread safe, but could there be the problem, that i access this RealmManager singleton from different threads, and its not thread safe with swifts singleton mechanism static let shared = RealmManager()?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code you are using to retrieve and store data? It would be very helpful for us to figure out whether you might be using Realm incorrectly, or whether there is a problem with Realm.